# getExtra on Fragment returning null

Tags: android

I have one activity that starts other activity:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("Data", data);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
 startActivity(intent);
```

This is MyActivity:

```
private GridViewPager pager;
private DotsPageIndicator dotsPageIndicator;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_teste);
    pager = (GridViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new GridPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()));
    dotsPageIndicator = (DotsPageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.page_indicator);
    dotsPageIndicator.setDotFadeWhenIdle(false);
    dotsPageIndicator.setPager(pager);
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            pager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

This is one Fragment included on pager.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_lista_atividades, container, false);
       if(getActivity().getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("Data")!=null) {
        Log.w("AAAAaA","HJKH");
    }
    return view;
}
```

I want to know why this line:

```
getActivity().getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("Data")
```

is returning null.

Comment: I'd recommend using EventBus for sending data between different activities, fragments and other components. It's much easier.

Comment: use getArguments() instead of getIntent()